# HTML: How to display advanced unicode in bold text?

Tags: html, css

Setting the font-weight to bold does not display advanced unicode characters.

```
<div style="font-weight: bold;">Test</div> ==> character does not display

<div style="font-weight: normal;">Test</div> ==> displays normally
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/72kznzah/1/

How can you still set the font-weight to bold without losing the character?

Comment: Make sure you have a font which includes the bold version of that character.

Comment: your fiddle works for me

Comment: For me, it displays normally (the bold smiley even looks a little bolder than the normal one ;)). Seems to be a browser specific thing. Using Firefox 45.0.1.

Comment: It seems it only doesn't work on Chrome on a Mac. Safari and Firefox display it normally though.

Comment: Chrome on Windoze is OK. Might be a Mac/Chrome joint issue.

Comment: That looks like a bug, I guess you'll have to wrap part of the text into spans and set bold to them - https://jsfiddle.net/72kznzah/3/ for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

It actually does set it to bold. It's working on my maching using your fiddle.
[image]

Comment: I see, it seems it only doesn't work on Chrome on a Mac. Safari and Firefox display it normally though.

Comment: Just wondering how did you get the yellow color to the emoji? I see it plain black in my machine :)

Comment: @ChristopherMasser, I'm actually on Chrome, on a Mac! Macbook Pro 13" (2015) using Chrome Dev version 51.0.2700.0